# How to find each point's height of a projectile?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, projectile

Tom in $20$ m/s velocity he kicked a ball with $60^\circ$ angle with vertical line. $30$ meters away from the place Tom kicked the ball, there is a goal post whose height is $1.8$ meters. If there is no goalkeeper, can this ball enter into the goal post or not?

[image]

By this question above, how can I calculate the height of the ball, where the range of the ball $R$ is $30$ meters? Specifically, when something travels in a projectile, how can I calculate his each point's height?

Comment: Hint : Taking time reqd as $t$ , find horizontal and vertical distance travelled ...

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

I won't provide you the full solution but I'll tell you the steps.

1. Find the time taken to travel 30 meters (You know the horizontal velocity).
2. Find the height of the ball at this instant using basic kinematic equations.

Simple enough?

Comment: i know, that i need to find "Find the height of the ball at this instant using basic kinematic equations." this term. My problem is actually here, how can i get the height of the ball where the range is in 30 meters.

Comment: Do you know how to find the displacement of a particle at an instant of time %t%, given the acceleration $a$ and  initial velocity $u$? If yes, this question should be piece of cake. If not, don't even waste time replying and go attend your lectures or read your textbooks.